# working with collections inside phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, php, phtml

I have this code, that return collection to my phtml template - work perfectly:

```
class Namespace_Tabs_Block_Content extends Mage_Core_Block_Template

public function getProducts()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')

                    ->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('in' => array(27, 26, 20)))

                    ->addFieldToFilter('status','1')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(2,4)));

    return $collection;
}
```

and this part of phtml :

```
<?php $_items = $this->getProducts() ?>

<div class="block">

    <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
        <div class="product">
            <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="
                <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>"
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

but when im trying to display each collection for color attribute - my inner foreeach shows nothink. this code, where somethink wrong

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $productsByColor = array('red' => $collection->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => 26)),
                             'blue' => $collection->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => 27)),
                             'black' => $collection->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => 20)),
                            );
    return $productsByColor;
}
```

phtml

```
<?php $products = $this->getProducts() ?>
<div class="block container">
<?php foreach ($products as $color => $_items): ?>

    <div class="block-content table" id="<?php echo $color ?>" >
        <div class="tab"> <?php echo $color ?> </div>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
           ... nothink here ...
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$collection` is an object so it is passed by reference. 
So when you call `addAttributeToFilter`  on the second row (for blue) you are adding a filter to the same collection you used on the first row (for red).
So in the end you get something that translates into SQL like this:

```
where color = 'red' and color = 'blue' and color = 'black'
```

Obviously you are going to get the a blank result.
So make your code look like this:

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $productsByColor = array();
    $red = clone $collection;
    $red->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => 26));
    $productsByColor['red'] = $red;

    $blue = clone $collection;
    $blue->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => 27));
    $productsByColor['blue'] = $blue;

    $black = clone $collection;
    $black->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' => 20));
    $productsByColor['black'] = $black;
    return $productsByColor;
}
```

**[EDIT]**
Or try this other approach

```
public function getProducts()
{
    $config = array('red' => 26, 'blue' => 27, 'black' => 20);
    $productsByColor = array();
    foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
         $productsByColor[$key] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('color', $value);
    }
    return $productsByColor;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Marius, for ur reply. good solution, already copied, but got this magento error : **You cannot define a correlation name 'at_color' more than once**

Comment: See my update. I have an alternative